# Finding the minimum number of cards to be drawn Generalized Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose you have a drawer with cards on which a number $1$ through $18$ is written. You can pick cards from the drawer with your eyes closed. What is the minimum number of cards you have to draw to guarantee that two of the drawn cards sum up to $9$ and two of the other drawn cards sum up to $27$.

I have found the number of ways to sum $9$ and $27$ but I am stuck on how to prove a minimum number of cards being drawn. Even if I find the probability of the sum of $27$ being drawn by two cards, and the probability of that of $9$, given conditional probability of $P(27|9)$, I would still not be able to find the minimum. Hence, is this using the pigeonhole principle? If so, how?

$9: (4,5) , (3,6), (2,7) , (1,8)$

$27: (13,14), (12,15), (11,16),(10,17), (9,18)$

Comment: Note:   the question in the header is not the same as the question in the body.  The minimum to have a possible success is obviously four.  The minimum to guarantee a success is clearly eighteen since $9$ or $18$ might be the last one drawn.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Do you understand my argument that the minimum number needed to guarantee a success is eighteen?  Was that in fact what you intended to ask?

Comment: @lulu I meant the question in the body. The header was my attempt at summarizing the below question. My bad and thanks

Comment: Ok.  And, to be clear, what I said was incorrect.  There are several ways to get $27$ as a sum...$17+10,16+11$ and so on.  Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

*What is the minimum number of cards you have to draw to guarantee that two of the drawn cards sum up to 9 and two of the other drawn cards sum up to 27 ?*

The answer is **$15$** cards.

Indeed, if you have drawn only $14$ cards, then the $4$ remaining ones might be : $1,2,3,4$ (or $8,2,6,5$ : there are 16 possibilities). Then no pair of cards sums to $9$.

If you have drawn at least $15$ cards, then for at least one of the four pairs summing to $9$, both cards are included. Similarly, at least two of the five possible pairs summing to $27$ is complete.

---

Yes, this can be presented with the pigeonhole principle: if the holes are the cards remaining in the drawer, and the pigeons are the pairs summing to $9$, then four pairs could be present in three holes only with two pairs in the same hole: since the pairs are mutually disjoint, this is impossible.

Comment: Based on the same reasoning for the sum of 27, would you say that a minimum of 14 cards must be drawn to get 27? Since there are 5 cards (13,12,11,10,9) that if left undrawn would cause no pair of cards to sum up to 27 when 13 cards are drawn. Hence, when at least 14 cards are drawn, then at least one of the 5 pairs would sum up to 27? thanks

Comment: @MunchiesOats : yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you! What if this was a combined case to draw the sums of 9 and 27, would it be to assume that when 9 cards are being drawn,  (1,2,3,4) and (13,12,11,10,9) are not going to be drawn, so no pairs could form 9 or 27. Can it be 10 cards or must it be 11 since we need one card from each set? thanks again in advance!

Comment: If you want to be sure to have either a pair summing to 9 or a pair summing to 18, you need to draw 10 cards.